# Change drop down list depending on input content

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu

I want to emulate this [booking form](https://booking.patrickegwutransport.com/).

If pickup is not an airport in the drop down list, it swaps to a google maps autocomplete drop down list.

I have a database and can show the two drop down lists independently. What I want to achieve is that as you type - depending on the input content - hide one list and show the other one. (That is how I think it's done according to the website code).

If anyone could shed some light I would be very grateful.

I asked web admin but doesn't know because it has been done for him

[image]

Comment: You need to create your database structure first. Do you already have it?

Comment: Yes, I do have a database and know how to show the two drop down forms independently. I want to hide one and show the other one depending on the input content.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript, the first drop down pass the id to the next one and you filter the next dropdown with that id.

Comment: Which part do you need help with reading the text being entered or hiding the other drop down? Or both?

Comment: I want to show different drop downs depending on the text being entered. If text written is not in the initial drop down list, show a second drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the functions you could use
You may want to save the lengths and check if the length changes.

```
    var dd1 = document.getElementById("dd1").value; 
    var dd2 = document.getElementById("dd2").value; 
    if(dd1.value.length >0 ){dd2.style.display = 'none'}
    if(dd2.value.length >0 ){dd1.style.display = 'none'}
```

Or add an onkeypress event

```
dd1.onkeypress="checkkeystroke(1)" 
dd1.addEventListener("keypress", function(){checkkeystroke(1);};
<input id="dd1" type="text onkeypress="checkkeystroke(1)" />;


<script>
var dropdown = [null,null,null];
const toggle = {1:[2],2:[1]}; 

dropdown[1] = document.getElementById("dd1");
dropdown[2] = document.getElementById("dd2");

function checkkeypress(id){
  dropdown[id] = dropdown[toggle[id]].style.display = 'none';
}
</style>
```

That's just some basic possibilities.   You would probably need to add some integrity checks.  You do not want to hide both entry inputs

### UPDATE

> I want to show different drop downs depending on the text being
> entered - and not in its length. If text written is not in the initial
> drop down list, show a second drop down list

So instead of getting the length you have the "value" of the text which I needed to to get the length.  
You may want to get the length and segment your list of words by length. Maybe not.

Make and array of the wordlist

```
 const wordlist = ['','','','','','',''];
```

if you have a different wordlist for each dropdown
then use an object instead of an array

```
 const wordlist = {0:['','','','','','',''],1:['','','','','','',''],2:['','','','','','',''];
```

You need to use consecutivly numbered ids in your dropdowns
e.g.
`<select id="dd0"><select id="dd1"><select id="dd2">`

The following will search your wordlist and if it finds a word in teh text value it makes dropdown #3 disappear and dropdown #4 aapear.

```
<script>
wordlist['','','','','','',''];
var dd= [null,null,null];
for (var id in dd){
  dd[id] = document.getElementById('dd' + id);
}

function keystroke(id){
  for (for var key in wordlist){
    if (dd[id].value.includes(wordlist[key])){
       dd[3].style.display = 'none';
       dd[4].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This should get you going if you understand my code.  There are some things I'd like to explain but a client just called and I need to go back to work. I do not know your programming level.  My code may be a little on the advanced side.  It will be very fast and can handle a large word list so you may want to include common misspellings in your word list. If you have questions I'll be around later.    There may be errors in my syntax I did not proof read the code.  No time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't think this solves my question. I want to show different drop downs depending on the text being entered - and not in its lenght. If text written is not in the initial drop down list, show a second drop down list.

Comment: I thought I had asked that question.  Okay I see you just now answered the question I asked 2 days ago.  I was not sure what you were specifically looking for, so my answer was very general. Now I see you are looking for specific words  A specific list of words?    Do you understand the onkeypress is the key to this routine?  You did no answer if you knew how to show and hide the drop downs?